# How to implement a fluent interface with Promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, synchronization, es6-promise

I want to make this code work

```
$('start') // push initial value to an array
.addItem(2) // add another value
.printAll() // print everything in array
.delay(2000) // wait x seconds
.addItem(5)
.printAll()
.start(); // execute all the commands before this line
```

I created a class with data array to hold the items. and steps array to hold the operations. Then i used chainable promises to execute them. is that the best way to do what i'm trying to achieve? Do I really need to store the operations in an array?

```
 class Sync {

        constructor() {}

        init(startValue) {
            this.data = [startValue];
            this.steps = [];
            return this;
        }

        addItem(value) {
            const append = (v)=>this.data.push(v);
            this._addStep(append, value);
            return this;
        }

        printAll() {
            this._addStep(v=>console.log(v.join()), this.data);
            return this;
        }

        delay(value) {
            this._addStep(window.setTimeout, value);
            return this;
        }

        _addStep(fun, ...args) {
            this.steps.push({
                fun,
                args
            });
        }

        start() {
            let start = Promise.resolve();
            this.steps.forEach(({fun, args})=>{
                start = start.then(()=>{
                    return new Promise(resolve=>{
                        if (fun === window.setTimeout) {
                            setTimeout(resolve, ...args);
                        } else {
                            fun.apply(this, args);
                            resolve();
                        }

                    }
                    );
                }
                );
            }
            );

            return this;
        }
    }
    const lib = new Sync();
    const $ = lib.init.bind(lib);
    $('start')
    .addItem(2)
    .printAll()
    .delay(2000)
    .addItem(5)
    .printAll()
    .start();
```

Comment: Since your code works, this question belongs to code review

Comment: Are you familiar with eventEmitter, maybe try with that approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your question belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ according to me, I tried to think of another implementation without Promises. It works with closures and callbacks only:

```js
class Sync {

    constructor() {}

    init(startValue) {
        this.data = [startValue];
        this.steps = [];
        return this;
    }

    addItem(value) {
        const append = v => this.data.push(v);
        this._addStep(append, value);
        return this;
    }

    printAll() {
        this._addStep(v => console.log(v.join()), this.data);
        return this;
    }

    delay(value) {
        this._addStep(window.setTimeout, value);
        return this;
    }

    _addStep(fun, ...args) {
        this.steps.push({
            fun,
            args
        });
    }

    start() {
        let finalFunction;
        this.steps.reverse().forEach(({ fun, args }) => {
            if (fun === window.setTimeout) {
                finalFunction = finalFunction ? encloseFunctionWithArgs(null, null, finalFunction, next => setTimeout(next, ...args)) : null;
            } else {
                finalFunction = encloseFunctionWithArgs(fun, args, finalFunction);
            }

        });
        finalFunction();
        return this;
    }
}

function encloseFunctionWithArgs(fun, args, next, trigger) {
    return function () {
        if (fun)
            fun(args);
        if (next)
            trigger ? trigger(next) : next();
    }
}

const lib = new Sync();
const $ = lib.init.bind(lib);
$('start')
.addItem(2)
.printAll()
.delay(2000)
.addItem(5)
.printAll()
.start();
```

**EDIT**

I finally managed to achieve what you want:

```js
const base = {
  init(startValue) {
    this.promise = new Promise(resolve => this.start = resolve).then(() => [startValue]);
    return this;
  },

  addItem(value) {
    this.promise = this.promise.then(v => [...v, value]);
    return this;
  },

  printAll() {
    this.promise.then(v => v.join()).then(console.log);
    return this;
  },

  delay(value) {
    this.promise = this.promise.then(v => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(v), value)));
    return this;
  }
}

const factory = base => arg => Object.create(base).init(arg);

const $ = factory(base);

$('start')
.addItem(2)
.printAll()
.delay(2000)
.addItem(5)
.printAll()
.start();
```

Comment: I'm trying to come up with an approach that doesn't require storing the operations until start is invoked

Comment: where would be the operations then?

Comment: replace the operations array with one promise with chain of handlers(each handler return a promise too) the original promise won't be fulfilled until start is invoked

Comment: I see, it would work with my solution as well, the `finalFunction` would be scoped to `Sync` and computed on the fly (on every call of the fluent interface) and `start` would only call `finalFunction`

Comment: It's actually not possible to build `finalFunction` on the fly because of the `.reverse()`... I need all of the data before starting to build it since I'm building a kind of "onion" starting from the center. I'm gonna stop trying, thanks for the brain exercise, I'd be glad to know the solution if you find one!

Comment: I finally managed to achieve what you asked, it's actually much shorter!

Comment: this is very clever. this.start = resolve  thank you so much for you help