# Async/await functionality in an object that returns an instance of itself (for chaining)

Tags: javascript

I have an instance of a class:

```
let myInstance = new MyObject();
```

that looks like this:

```
export default class MyObject () {
    constructor () {}

    methodOne () {
        // Do stuff …
        return this;
    }

    async methodTwo () {
        let db_query = await Connection.query('<DATABASE QUERY>');

        return this;
    }

    methodThree () {
        // Do stuff …
        return this;
    }

    // etc.
}
```

This way I can chain methods on the instance:

```
myInstance
    .methodOne()
    .methodTwo()
    .methodThree()
```

How can I make sure that `methodTwo` won't return (`this`) until the `async`/`await` is resolved?

Doing something like this (won't work):

```
let db_query = await Connection.query('<DATABASE QUERY>');

    db_query
        .then(() => {
            return this:
        })
```

**Note**: `myInstance` is itself wrapped in an `async`/`await` method.

Comment: You can't. `methodTwo` returns a _promise_, which later gets resolved with `this`, when the `await` is reached. `async` functions always return promises. With the current implementation you'd have to do e.g. `myInstance.methodOne().methodTwo().then((i) => i.methodThree())`. Or use something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/59586425/3001761.

Comment: With `await`, you can also try `(await myInstance.methodOne().methodTwo()).methodThree()`, but the reasoning from the comment above holds.

Answer (score 2):

`methodTwo` returns a promise, like [all `async` functions do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302431/async-await-implicitly-returns-promise). It's a promise that will be fulfilled with `this`, or rejected if the operation it awaits rejects. There's nothing you can do to make `methodTwo` wait synchronously for the asynchronous result from `Connection.query`. JavaScript's run-to-completion, one-active-thread-per-realm semantics don't allow that.

Since `methodTwo` returns a promise, to use the chaining, you'd have to await the result of `methodTwo`:

```
(await myInstance
    .methodOne()
    .methodTwo())
    .methodThree()
```

...which isn't...beautiful, but isn't too bad. :-) Or if you're doing this where you can't use `await`, you'd need `then` (at minumum, probably also `catch`):

```
myInstance
    .methodOne()
    .methodTwo()
    .then((t) => t.methodThree()); // Or don't use `t` and use `myInstance`
```

...which is probably even less beautiful. :-)

This is just a fundamental aspect of asynchronous operations in JavaScript.

You could make `methodTwo` *not* `async` and have it return `this` before the `Connection.query` operation completes, but I suspect you don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a queue of functions to execute (they can be async or not), and then have a `complete()` function that you can `await` in order to wait for the chain to sequentially complete:

```js
class MyObject {
  constructor() {
    this.queue = []
  }

  methodOne() {
    this.queue.push(async () => await pause('A'));
    return this;
  }

  methodTwo() {
    this.queue.push(async () => await pause('B'));
    return this;
  }

  methodThree() {
    this.queue.push(async () => await pause('C'));
    return this;
  }
  
  async complete() {
    while(this.queue.length) await this.queue.shift()();
  }

}

async function pause(msg) {
  let ms = Math.random()*2000|0;
  console.log(`${msg}: pausing for ${ms} ms`)
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`${msg}: completed pause of ${ms} ms`);
    resolve();
  }, ms))
}

let myInstance = new MyObject();

(async () => {
  await myInstance.methodOne().methodTwo().methodThree().complete()
})();
```